# for a std::function how can one easily determine if the captures requre allocation (or not)

Tags: c++, std-function

An instance of `std::function` has space in itself for containing a limited size of "captured" arguments.  to avoid thrashing memory allocations I want to make sure some of the instances of `std::function` I use do not require an extra allocation for the arguments.

For a specific platform/header is there an easy way to determine what the max size of captures is before it makes a secondary allocation for them ?

Comment: You could write a test app that overrides global `operator new` and tries to copy bigger and bigger captures until the `operator new` gets called. Run this as part of project setup and write the results to a header file `inferred_implement_details.h` or something like that. This is basically how CMake detects platform attributes.

Answer (score 4):

From [constructor's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), emphasize mine:

> When the target is a **function pointer or a `std::reference_wrapper`**, **small object optimization is guaranteed**, that is, these targets are always directly stored inside the `std::function` object, no dynamic allocation takes place. Other large objects may be constructed in dynamic allocated storage and accessed by the std::function object through a pointer.

So, from standard, you have guaranty for function pointer, and `std::reference_wrapper` (but no ownership for this one).

Else you have to read constructor code of your library/compiler.

For gcc, the condition is (from [std_function.h#L124](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/std_function.h#L124)):

```
static const size_t _M_max_size = sizeof(_Nocopy_types);
static const size_t _M_max_align = __alignof__(_Nocopy_types);

// ...

static const bool __stored_locally =
(__is_location_invariant<_Functor>::value
 && sizeof(_Functor) <= _M_max_size
 && __alignof__(_Functor) <= _M_max_align
 && (_M_max_align % __alignof__(_Functor) == 0));
```

Comment: "_So, from standard, you have guaranty for function pointer, and std::reference_wrapper (but no ownership for this one)._": The linked cppreference page is wrong. This is only a "_recommended practice_" and worded with "_should_", i.e. not a normative requirement. See https://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#func.wrap.func.con-5.

Comment: @user17732522 I agree it's not an ironclad guarantee, but it's guaranteed for practical purposes. The preceding paragraph implies that it must have some way to guarantee that it finds space to store the callable in even if `operator new` fails. Theoretically, it could try `operator new` first and then fall back to some alternative allocation technique, but that seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, I overlooked the preceding paragraph.

Comment: well - alas sort of "it aint easy" like getting a 
func.maxCaptureSize() value :)

I have put a break point on the alloc in the past and then run an instantiation and see if it gets hit or not.  I guess that is what one has to do !!